# How to add bundles and resources like images in that bundle in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bundle

I created bundle using `i-phone-OS->resources->setting` but I am unable to add images to this bundle. I tried dragging images folder or by adding existing to folder but nothing works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The Settings.bundle is added as a folder/bundle reference and not as a group.

Thus you won't be able to easily add some content to it right from the Groups & Files panel in Xcode unfortunately. Instead, go in the Finder, right-click (or ctrl-click) on this Settings.bundle and select "Show Package Contents" then drag & drop files in there. You will then find the added files back in Xcode.

*I also find this kinda anoying in Xcode3 that we can't add files to '.bundle' folders/bundles  directly from Xcode3 :( But AFAIK there is no other solution*

One your file has been added to the '.bundle', you can edit them directly from Xcode. (Going thru the Finder is only necessary for adding new files to it)